# Python : resplit an optionparser list

Tags: python, list, split, optparse

I need to analyze all the signatures I've got in input.
For example my input can be :

`$ python script.py -i 4:64+0:0:1460:mss*20,7:mss,sok,ts,nop,ws:df:0`

I would like to split this input at `:` and `,`, so that I end up with a list that looks like this:

`['4', '64', '0', '1460', 'mss*20', '7', 'mss', 'sok', 'ts', 'nop', 'ws', 'df', '0']`

I can then do a loop or index to analyze the position of my item.
My program works when I use the functions `input()` and `re.split()`.
But not when i want to put my signature in arguments with `optparse`.

If someone can help me that would be nice, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is simple. The magic are string functions: `replace` and `split`. Function `split` split string with given separator to the list. But you cannot use any spaces in your parsed string, because the `argparse` would think it is other commandline argument.

Here is complete code of `script.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*

import argparse

DESCRIPTION=u"My parser"
def InitParser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(DESCRIPTION)
    parser.add_argument(
        '-i', '--input', 
        help=u"Parameter splitted by comma or column"
    )
    return parser

def main():
    parser = InitParser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print "Parser args=", args
    print
    if args.input:
        lst = args.input.replace(':',',').split(',')
        print "Splited -i argument:"
        print(lst)
    else:
        print "Missing -i argument"
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Program output:**

```
C:\temp\tem>script.py -i 4:64+0:0:1460:mss*20,7:mss,sok,ts,nop,ws:df:0
Parser args= Namespace(input='4:64+0:0:1460:mss*20,7:mss,sok,ts,nop,ws:df:0')

Splited -i argument:
['4', '64+0', '0', '1460', 'mss*20', '7', 'mss', 'sok', 'ts', 'nop', 'ws', 'df', '0']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !!